# Thread Debug, Want A Name

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging

Still trying to debug 3 different threads.

I can see that the threads are cooperating; sortta; sometimes; but I can't really see which thread is doing what.

The "console" window shows me things like this...

```
The thread '< No Name >' (0x14a4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '< No Name >' (0xec8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '< No Name> ' (0x15a8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I thought it would be great to put a name with these hex values that don't tell me anything.

I looked on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [this other one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/581hfskb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which were probably accurate, but I missed the part on where you change `<No Name>` to something like `Background Rx` or `Label1_Text_Change` or whatever.

Example...

```
this.demoThread =
     new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Antarctica));

this.demoThread.Start();
```

I hate being the site's leading dunce, but could someone please demonstrate, in this three line example (really it's two lines, but whatever) how do I tell C# and Visual Studio to change `<no name>` to `Antarctica` ? I'm talking about watching the sequence in the console window a the bottom of the Visual Studio IDE.

If it matters, the app is displayed on one screen while the Visual Studio IDE is displayed on the other.

Answer (score 6):

```
this.demoThread.Name = "Antarctica";
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. This place is exactly where I want to be

Answer (score 2):

```
this.demoThread =
     new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Antarctica)){Name = "Antarctica"};

this.demoThread.Start();
```

Comment: Super; maybe even better. Just learned, you have to use one way or the other, IDE gets mad if you try to change the name. Whatever, thanks a ton.